# Stretch sf::Sprite across entire window

Tags: c++, sfml

I have a sf::Sprite and when drawing it to the window I want it to fill the entire window.

sf::RenderWindow.draw takes an optional sf::RenderStates. Is that what I need to mess with?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Resizing in SFML 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21363557/resizing-in-sfml-2-0)

Comment: @EmileBergeron This question’s almost 6 years old idk

Comment: It's an automated comment, as I've realized it should be marked as a duplicate (since my answer is just the same as the other question).

Comment: @EmileBergeron sure mark it as dup then

Comment: It's already done (I can only vote), that's where the automated comment comes from. It's a weird feature, I know...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, [basic Sprite usage](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.0/graphics-sprite.php) from the tutorial.

Taken from my own answer on [Resizing in SFML 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21363557/1218980) which, by the way, is the first google result when searching for "sfml sprite fill the screen".

> First, here's a way to scale the image to the current RenderWindow
>   size.
>
> ```
> // assuming the given dimension
> // change this dynamically with the myRenderWindow->getView().getSize()
> sf::Vector2f targetSize(900.0f, 1200.0f); 
>
> yourSprite.setScale(
>     targetSize.x / yourSprite.getLocalBounds().width, 
>     targetSize.y / yourSprite.getLocalBounds().height);
> ```
>
> Be aware that this may stretch your image if the aspect ratio is not
>   maintained. You might want to add code to adjust the decision for your
>   case.
>
> Then, if you want to stretch the RenderWindow to fill all the screen,
>   may I suggest you use fullscreen mode?
>
> Here's a snippet of how it's done:
>
> ```
> // add the flag to the other ones
> mStyleFlag = sf::Style::Default | sf::Style::Fullscreen;
>
> // get the video mode (which tells you the size and BPP information of the current display
> std::vector<sf::VideoMode> VModes = sf::VideoMode::getFullscreenModes();
>
> // then create (or automatically recreate) the RenderWindow
> mMainWindow.create(VModes.at(0), "My window title", mStyleFlag);
> ```

If you're looking for a background, the most elegant way to do it would probably be to just define a sf::VertexArray which will render a quad filling your window using the correct texture coordinates.

This was taken from the second google result: [What happened to sprite::setSize in SFML2?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/57330/15814)