# SFML Texture Transforming (Enlarging)

Tags: c++, sfml

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>    

int main()
{
    int desktopwidth = sf::VideoMode::getDesktopMode().width;
    int desktopheight = sf::VideoMode::getDesktopMode().height;
    sf::ContextSettings settings;settings.antialiasingLevel = 8;
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(desktopwidth, desktopheight), "Texture Transforming!", sf::Style::Fullscreen, settings);
    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Image image;
        if (!(image.loadFromFile("texture.jpg")))
            std::cout << "Cannot load image";   //Load Image
        sf::Texture texture;
        texture.loadFromImage(image);  //Load Texture from image
        sf::Sprite sprite;
        sprite.setTexture(texture);
        sprite.setTextureRect({ 0, 0, desktopwidth, desktopheight });
        window.clear();
        window.draw(sprite);
        window.display();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

What I want to do is stretch the texture to the full size of the screen when the screen is bigger than the image. Using setTextureRect all I have achieved is stretching out the last pixel to the new size which isn't a great look for what i am trying to do, as image resize was removed, does anyone know of a work around to resize images or transform texture size/scales?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resizing in SFML 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21363557/resizing-in-sfml-2-0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sf::Sprite::setTextureRect()` defines the part of the texture that's visible as the sprite. It doesn't define the actual display size.

For this purpose you might want to use [`sf::Sprite::setScale()`](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.0/classsf_1_1Transformable.php#aaec50b46b3f41b054763304d1e727471), which allows you to define a scaling ratio. For example, calling `sprite.setScale(2, 2);` will make the displayed sprite twice as wide/high.

If you want to downscale/upscale your whole scene, you might want looking into `sf::View` though.